# Can we modify an OpenCart extension and upload it?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I want to know if is it Ok to modify a free extension to support the newer version of opencart and upload it to extension directory for free or price?

If yes, can you please tell me what should I care about while doing this? Like giving credit to the author whose extension I modified?

> I am not sure if asking this here is alright but I couldn't find anything about this so posted this question

Comment: Read the supplied license (if any), or ask the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opencart is not like Wordpress, that the plugins published with a GPL license.

If you upload any extension like another first extension the most probably is that your account will be banned. If the author extension is not free, your account will be banned.

If the extension is free you can put the author credits in the documentation about your extension.

In my opinion if you want to upload a better version, you must talk with the first author. Send an email.

In any case, if you want to upload a FREE extension you only have to register here https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/login
login up and follow the step, are very easy.

If you want to upload a NON free extension. you need a seller account

When your account are ok
Go here again, login  https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/login  and then you will have to fill other form to change your acount to a seller acount.
Then you will have to wait 1 or 2 week to receipt and email to tell that your account it's right